# In Xcode 4.4.1 or 4.5, is there Simulator IOS 6 included?

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode4.4, ios6, xcode4.5

In Xcode 4.4.1 or 4.5, is there Simulator IOS 6 included? 
Or except jailbreak, il there a official way to get ios 6 installed?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To develop for iOS 6 you need xcode 4.5. Xcode 4.4.1 supports only 5.1 iOS version
- If you're enrolled to apple ios developer program you can download iOS6 firmware from apple dev site

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In fact I juste need to test in a ios6 device or simulator. So my question was is there a simulator integrated in XCode4.5? I didn't find an official ios6 firmware on dev center, could you please give a link?

Comment: Yes, iOS 6 should be in Xcode 4.5 distribution. Once you log in to dev center (https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) you'll see link to iOS 6 sdk beta.